# Howto know if tab is selected inside Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Inside a tab fragment

`public class ClassViewFragment extends Fragment {`

Is there a function in which I can catch the event of tab selection?

I know I can catch this inside main activity class in `onTabSelected` but I want to know if such thing possible inside the fragment class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a `TabHost`? It's tough to say from your snippet, but if you are you can just implement `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener` and put your code in `onTabChanged`.